# Update ListObject in Excel --> Error Access Database Blocked

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a Access Database running as a normal file on a shared drive. Some tables from this database are available to users to read through Excel Files with ListsObjects.

These ListObjects need to be refreshed regularly to be up-to-date. Currently I am doing that manually.

I want to do this automatically by running a VBA code in the access database to open each file and in each files all the ListObjects to refresh them.

However, if I run the ListObject.refresh() method I get an error message that the database is blocked. If I do the refresh manually it works perfectly. In both cases I have the database open, so that can't be the problem.

This is the error message:

> The database has been placed in a state by an user ("here is my user ID") that
>   prevents it from being opened or locked. (Error 3733)

Thank you for any suggestions.

Here is the part of the code:

```
Set ExlFile = app.Workbooks.Add(myWB)
For Each mySheet In ExlFile.Worksheets
    For Each myLO In mySheet.ListObjects
        myLO.Refresh
    Next
Next
```

UPDATE:
If I use the function compact and repair on the database, it works for 3-5 files and then it stops working again.

Does anyone know what Application.CompactRepair does? I have a very bad solution for my problem now, I added Application.CompactRepair to each iteration. Now it works but of course it takes very long. It seems to me Application.CompactRepair somehow resets some status in the DB and it would be a better solution to do that directly.

Comment: what is your excel version?

Comment: Excel and Access 2016

Comment: what is your vba code?
have you try `listobject.querytable.refresh()`?

Comment: Yes, same problem

Comment: what if `listobject.querytable.refresh(false)` ?

Comment: Just tried it, same error. Like I wrote in my update, I suspect there is some varibale set in the DB blocking the access from excel.

Comment: `listobject.querytable.MaintainConnection = False`

Comment: @PaichengWu, thank you for putting so much effort into solving my problem. Sadly your last suggestion also does not work.

Comment: How do you create these listobjects?  by VBA?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176122/discussion-between-paichengwu-and-franksta).

Comment: Sorry, I was AFK in meetings. The listobjects are created by adding data tables in excel manually.

Comment: I would *highly* suggest **not** using Compact & Repair to solve / bandage this problem. That being said, the error you are running into is what happens when a database is locked for editing, based on your code snippet you have, there is nothing being updated, perhaps there is some other effect happening here in some other concurrent running code, or manual editing? What you *may* want to try, is replicating this problem with a fresh **new** database.